# upload sqlite database file with html form and show its tables on submit

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to upload an SQLite db file and show it on next page. the problem is in the path of SQLite db file..when I give this path **uploads/test.db** than its work but when I give path via **uploads/$fname** than it does not work.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

   Move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
        $fname = basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        echo $fname;



   $db = new SQLite3('uploads/$fname');
    $tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';");

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        if ($table['name'] != "sqlite_sequence") {
            echo $table['name'] . ' <br />';
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db = new SQLite3('uploads/$fname');
```

You are using single quotes, not double quotes, so PHP is not [expanding the variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) `$fname` with its value. PHP is trying to open the literal path `uploads/$fname` and, of course, doesn't find anything.

Change the line to use double quotes, like so:

```
$db = new SQLite3("uploads/$fname");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add yours to the absolute local path.

```
$target_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/uploads/";
So your final $$target_dir will be like /var/www/html/project/uploads/filename
```

And `move_uploaded_file()` never creates the folders, So you should have created the uploads folder yourself.